Firebase not working on successful android builds despite working correctly in the editor
I am using unity to build an app, I've started to integrate firebase as my authentication method.
I've installed the SDK and copied over my google-services.json as the documentation instructs, I've created a class for my authManager and copied over the code from the docs for registration and logging in.
When i run my project through the IDE everything works correctly. I can register users, sign in, data is passed back and forth to firebase no issues.
However, when I build the apk and manually copy onto my android device, install the app and try to register/login there is no connection
I've done a little debugging through and have narrowed it to it maybe not creating my auth object correctly for whatever reason. (Probably much better ways to debug/check debug logs but still at the very beginning of my app building journey...). I put some text on the screen to try see whats happening
    void Start()
    {
        debugText.text = "starting...";
        FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
        {
            debugText.text = "test1";
            FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;
            debugText.text = "test2";
            auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
            debugText.text = "test3";
            Debug.Log("auth complete");
        });
        debugText.text = "finished";
    }

So on my android device the text stays as "starting..." (IDE goes to "finished" as expected)
So its having issues with "FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread"
Anyone had a similar issue? or maybe I have missed a step needed?
Some things I have seen online, asking copilot/chat gpt which I have tried but no luck have been:

Creating a custom AndroidManifest.xml file and giving permissions to access internet
Having google-services.json in Asset/ folder (not Asset/StreamingAsset like I had previously seen)
Adding

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="12451000" />
        <meta-data android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled" android:value="true" />

To AndroidManifest.xml
and some other little tweaks which I have probably forget

One thought is that maybe it only works if deployed via the app store, but have not seen or read anything to explain or confirm this?

Try checking the DependencyStatus as described in Add Firebase to your Unity project. This will help elaborate what is going on and perhaps how to fix it.
